# Uniquely identifying Google plus users

Tags: google-plus

When a user signs into my site using "Sign In With Google", I would like to store something unique about them (like a UUID) in my MySQL database, so I could store the users favorites.

Answer (score 1):

When the user signs in you get their email address which is probably what you are looking for in terms of a UUID.

Comment: I was thinking that but it seemed so wrong to use that to identify the user. Oh well! Thanks!

Comment: Why not? Most sites use email as a login since it's guaranteed to be unique. Once you insert the email into your database, you're free to use the row id instead to uniquely identify the user if you wish. Just make sure that you keep a unique constraint on the email column.